Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames. While using "@kubernetes/client-node" version 0.15 in ipv6 configuration only
I am using "@kubernetes/client-node" 0.15 version in my node project. The same configuration is working fine in the ipv4 configuration. But when same configuration and code is used in the ipv6 environment it tells that "Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames". Below is code snippet for the loading the configuration.
private constructor() {
    K8s.kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
    try {
      K8s.inCluster = Env.get("KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST", "false") !== "false";
      Logger.run_time.log("---------------host: ", Env.get("KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST", "false"));
      if (K8s.inCluster) {
        K8s.kc.loadFromCluster();
       
      } else {
        K8s.kc.loadFromDefault();
        Logger.run_time.log("---------------default: ", K8s.kc.clusters);
        console.log("---------------default: ", K8s.kc.clusters);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.run_time.error(LogDictionaryType.ERROR_K8S_CONNECT, e);
      console.log("--------------inside the error main ----------------------")
      console.error(LogDictionaryType.ERROR_K8S_CONNECT, e);
    }
  }

But while using ipv6 if I am disabling the TLS like below:
K8s.kc.addCluster({
          name: "cluster name",
          caFile: 'ca.crt',
          server: "https://[ip]:443",
          skipTLSVerify: false
        });


So it is working.
Please suggest any version of "@kubernetes/client-node" that I can move to solve this issue or any other fix that can fix this.
node version : 14
I was trying to upgrade to latest versions of the kubernetes client but that did not work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Apparently, IPv6 and IPv4 are encoded in certs as distinct. So, you should look at your certs. Look at https://serverfault.com/questions/980071/ipv6-address-in-ssl-certificate, to see an example.
